# Comparing objects returned by Boost.Bind?

Tags: c++, boost-bind

Is it possible? The instruction `bool b = (boost::bind(func, 1) == boost::bind(func, 1))` does not compile because it "cannot convert from 'boost::_bi::bind_t' to 'bool'". (The signature of `func` is `void func(int)`.)

Comment: Why would you compare function pointers or anything similar???

Comment: ... 'Cause I need to... Should I take that as a "no, it's not possible"?

Comment: No, I have no idea, but I don't think that the return type of boost::bind has operator== defined

Comment: Are you sure you need to? Maybe you're approaching your problem the wrong way

Comment: @Pablo Yes, I'm sure. I've been thinking about my particular problem for quite a few days now, and I finally found a very good solution... except it won't work unless you can somehow compare boost.bind. There's one other way I can fix my problem, but that would make the API slightly more complicated to use, so I'd rather not use it unless I'm certain there's no other way.

Comment: See also ["Why is std::function not equality comparable?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629835/why-is-stdfunction-not-equality-comparable)  The answers to that question also answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if this is "oficially supported functionality" but bind_t does seem to provide a `function_equal` method: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/boost/bind/bind.hpp

Comment: Hey, that seems very promising, thanks a lot. I'll test this tomorrow; I'm so tired right now. :)

Comment: Thank you, Pablo, it works. As an alternative you can also use the compare member function: `boost::bind(func, 1).compare(boost::bind(func, 1))`.

Answer (score 3):

Boost.Bind overloads the relational operators to return nested bind expressions. Thus in your code `boost::bind(func, 1) == boost::bind(func, 1)` returns a nullary (since there is no placeholders in your bind expressions) functor that, when called, returns `func(1) == func(1)`. This is a convenient feature for predicates, amongst other uses:

```
typeded std::pair<T, U> pair_type;
// find pair where the first element is equal to 3
std::find_if(begin, end, boost::bind(&pair_type::first, _1) == 3);
```

In addition, the returned object is not convertible to `bool` and this is why it won't compile (disregarding the issue that it doesn't do what you want).

What you want to do is not part of the Boost.Bind interface. Tt would not be a very useful feature and in the (very) general case is [undecidable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Undecidability_of_equivalence).