# compare two boost::function

Tags: c++, boost

```
void ff(int){} 

void Unscribe(const boost::function<void(int)>& f)
{
    std::map<int, boost::function<void(int)> > map;

    map[0] = ff;

    if( map[0] == f)
    {

    }  
}

Unscribe( ff );
```

I would like to be able to compare two boost::function with the same signature.
What should I modified to get this code compilable ?

Comment: See [Why is std::function not equality comparable?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3629835/20984)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't. Read the [boost function FAQ](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/function/faq.html)'s first entry:

> 1. Why can't I compare boost::function objects with operator== or
>      operator!=?
>
> Comparison between boost::function objects cannot be implemented
>   "well", and therefore will not be implemented. ...

Comment: why this cannot be implemented well?

Comment: @Guillaume07: The rest of the FAQ entry I posted a link to explains that. I thought better of copy-pasting the entire entry into the answer

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking to compare signatures, or functor equality (that two functors point to the same underlying memory address)? If its the latter, you can use the interface provided by `boost/function_equal.hpp`:

[Boost Function Equal](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost/function_equal.html)

```
template<typename F, typename G> bool function_equal(const F& f, const G& g);
```

Comment: Wrong answer, `function_equal` is only useful to allow the comparison of function *wrappers* (`boost::function`) with function *objects* (functors or function pointers) (see [Comparing Boost.Function function objects](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/function/tutorial.html#id1362038)). Comparison of two function wrappers is not possible. (I admit that the documentation is not very clear about that.)

Comment: This is what I want.