# Using std::unique_ptr for Windows HANDLEs

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, unique-ptr

I am attempting to use std::unique_ptrs to manage Windows HANDLEs in an exception-safe manner.

First I tried:

```
struct HandleDeleter
{
    void operator()( HANDLE handle )
    {
        if( handle )
        {
            FindVolumeClose( handle )
        }
    }
}
typedef std::unique_ptr< HANDLE, HandleDeleter > unique_vol_handle_t;
```

Later in my code when I try to use it:

`unique_vol_handle_t volH( FindFirstVolumeW( buffer, MAX_GUID_PATH ) );`

I get the following error from Visual Studio 2012RC:

```
1>          error C2664: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty,_Dx>::unique_ptr(std::nullptr_t) throw()' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'HANDLE' to 'std::nullptr_t'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=HANDLE,
1>              _Dx=VolumeHandleDeleter
1>          ]
1>          nullptr can only be converted to pointer or handle types
```

referencing the volH declaration line, immediately above.

After searching for some time, I found [a blog article](http://codesequoia.wordpress.com/2012/08/26/stdunique_ptr-for-windows-handles/#comment-45) which basically says, add:

`typedef HANDLE pointer;`

to the top of the struct declaration, and all will be well.

I didn't believe it, but I tried it and it did resolve the error.  I'm puzzled how defining a type (without even referencing it) could make such a difference.

Two questions:

1) Can you explain the original error?  I don't understand why the compiler is referring to `std::nullptr_t/nullptr`.

2) How is it that the typedef resolves this (or at least appears to)?  Is there a less 'spooky action at a distance' solution to this?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066721/what-are-the-uses-of-the-type-stdnullptr-t). might help with your wondering about `nullptr_t`.

Comment: Thanks, Joachim.  That does help with the nullptr messages.

Comment: +1 for the quantum mechanics reference

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The implementation of `unique_ptr` checks for the presence of a `::pointer` type on the deleter. If the deleter has a `::pointer` type then this type is used as the `pointer` typedef on the `unique_ptr`. Otherwise a pointer to the first template argument is used.

According to [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr#Member_types), the `unique_ptr::pointer` type is defined as

> `std::remove_reference<D>::type::pointer` if that type exists, otherwise `T*`

Comment: Thank you, Kevin for the clear explanation.  And by not defining the pointer type, I'm basically telling the deleter to use HANDLE* (void**) instead of HANDLE (void*), which is incorrect.

The compiler gave me the world's most cryptic error message, but your explanation is in plain English, so I'm accepting your answer--thank you!

Comment: Is that useful, though? The standard says that `operator*` returns `*get()`, but has return type `T &`, and `get()` has return type `pointer`.

Comment: For most handles 0 is a valid value and INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE is the invalid value, therefor this solution is not correct for most handle because the reset() of the unique_ptr will check for nullptr instead of INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE so you have to create your own wrapper class.

Comment: So the answer (for the lazy) is to add a `typedef` like the following:
`struct HandleDeleter
{
    typedef HANDLE pointer;

    void operator()( HANDLE handle )`
...

Answer (score 7):

I've been doing the following for various types of handles in Windows. Assuming we have declared somewhere:

```
std::unique_ptr<void, decltype (&FindVolumeClose)> fv (nullptr, FindVolumeClose);
```

This is populated with:

```
HANDLE temp = FindFirstVolume (...);
if (temp != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    fv.reset (temp);
```

No need to declare a separate struct to wrap the deleters. Since `HANDLE` is really a `void *` the `unique_ptr` takes `void` as its type; for other kinds of handles, that use the `DECLARE_HANDLE` macro, this can be avoided:

```
// Manages the life of a HHOOK
std::unique_ptr<HHOOK__, decltype (&UnhookWindowsHookEx)> hook (nullptr, UnhookWindowsHookEx);
```

And so on.

Comment: `HANDLE` is not `void*` if `STRICT` is defined. You can use `std::remove_pointer` instead of hard-coding the type, ie `std::remove_pointer<HANDLE>::type`, `std::remove_pointer<HHOOK>::type`, etc, that way you always have the correct type whether `STRICT` is defined or not

Comment: @RemyLebeau:  `STRICT` turns GDI and user handles (like `HBRUSH`, `HDC`, `HMONITOR`, `HINSTANCE`, `HKEY`, etc.) into distinct types.  But kernel `HANDLE`s are all `void *`, even the ones that require something other than `CloseHandle` to close them, like the ones returned from `FindFirstVolume`, `FindFirstFile`, etc.

Answer (score 6):

From the [MSDN manual on unique_ptr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee410601%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> The stored pointer to an owned resource, `stored_ptr` has type pointer. It is `Del::pointer` if defined, and `Type *` if not. The stored **deleter** object `stored_deleter` occupies no space in the object if the **deleter** is stateless. Note that Del can be a reference type.

This means that if you provide a deleter functor it have to provide a `pointer` type that is used for the actual pointer type of the `unique_ptr`. Otherwise it will be the a pointer to your provided type, in your case `HANDLE*` which isn't correct.

Comment: Hi, Joachim.  Kevin's explanation above is clearer to me than MSDN's language so I've accepted his answer.  But this does make sense now.  Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

The proper (and safe) way to use `std::unique_ptr` for Windows HANDLEs is something like this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <memory>

class WinHandle {
    HANDLE value_;
public:
    WinHandle(std::nullptr_t = nullptr) : value_(nullptr) {}
    WinHandle(HANDLE value) : value_(value == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ? nullptr : value) {}

    explicit operator bool() const { return value_ != nullptr; }
    operator HANDLE() const { return value_; }

    friend bool operator ==(WinHandle l, WinHandle r) { return l.value_ == r.value_; }
    friend bool operator !=(WinHandle l, WinHandle r) { return !(l == r); }

    struct Deleter {
        typedef WinHandle pointer;
        void operator()(WinHandle handle) const { CloseHandle(handle); }
    };
};

inline bool operator ==(HANDLE l, WinHandle r) { return WinHandle(l) == r; }
inline bool operator !=(HANDLE l, WinHandle r) { return !(l == r); }
inline bool operator ==(WinHandle l, HANDLE r) { return l == WinHandle(r); }
inline bool operator !=(WinHandle l, HANDLE r) { return !(l == r); }

typedef std::unique_ptr<WinHandle, WinHandle::Deleter> HandlePtr;
```

This way `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` is implicitly treated as null, and thus will never be passed to `CloseHandle` function and you never need to explicitly test for it. Use `std::unique_ptr`'s `operator bool()` instead, as you normally would:

```
HandlePtr file(CreateFile(...));
if (!file) {
    // handle error
}
```

**EDIT:** I originally forgot that `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` [is **not** the only *invalid value*](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040302-00/?p=40443) for the `HANDLE` type, and that in fact it is treated as a [*valid* pseudo handle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683179(v=vs.85).aspx) by many, if not most, kernel functions. Well, good to know.

Comment: Can you generalize this a little to allow different specializations? For example, WinHandle<FindClose>, vs WinHandle(CloseHandle), as well as for unique_ptr vs. shared_ptr?
Also, I wrapped the WinHandle in a namespace to deter it being used directly.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to take a look at [*A Proposal to Add additional RAII Wrappers to the Standard Library*](http://www.andrewlsandoval.com/scope_exit/) and at [*the drawbacks of using smart pointers with handles*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14878121).

Personally, I'm making use of the reference implementation of that proposal instead of using `std::unique_ptr` for these situations.

Comment: I can't say I fully agree with the 'drawbacks of using smart pointers with handles' premise, but I do appreciate the links to interesting and thought-provoking articles such as this.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Please, take a look at [Window Implementation Libraries](https://github.com/Microsoft/wil/wiki/RAII-resource-wrappers) (WIL) in particular at `unique_handle` vs `unique_hfile` for handling invalid handle values.

Answer (score -1):

While @Levi Haskell his answer takes INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE into account it does not take into account that 0 is a valid handle value and treats INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE and 0 (or nullptr) as the same. This is not correct:

My suggestion (based on Levi Haskell his code so credits to him)

```
template<void *taInvalidHandleValue>
class cWinHandle 
{
    HANDLE value_ { taInvalidHandleValue };
public:
    cWinHandle() = default;
    cWinHandle(HANDLE value) : value_(value) {}
    ~cWinHandle()
    {
        reset();
    }

    explicit operator bool() const { return value_ != taInvalidHandleValue; }
    operator HANDLE() const { return value_; }

    HANDLE get() const { return value_; }
    HANDLE release() { HANDLE const result{ value_ }; value_ = taInvalidHandleValue; return result; }
    friend bool operator ==(cWinHandle l, cWinHandle r) { return l.value_ == r.value_; }
    friend bool operator !=(cWinHandle l, cWinHandle r) { return !(l == r); }
    void reset ()
    {
        if (value_ != taInvalidHandleValue)
        {
            CloseHandle(value_);
            value_ = taInvalidHandleValue;
        }
    }
};

inline bool operator ==(HANDLE l, cWinHandle<nullptr> r) { return cWinHandle<nullptr>(l) == r; }
inline bool operator !=(HANDLE l, cWinHandle<nullptr> r) { return !(l == r); }
inline bool operator ==(cWinHandle<nullptr> l, HANDLE r) { return l == cWinHandle<nullptr>(r); }
inline bool operator !=(cWinHandle<nullptr> l, HANDLE r) { return !(l == r); }
inline bool operator ==(HANDLE l, cWinHandle<INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE> r) { return cWinHandle<INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE>(l) == r; }
inline bool operator !=(HANDLE l, cWinHandle<INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE> r) { return !(l == r); }
inline bool operator ==(cWinHandle<INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE> l, HANDLE r) { return l == cWinHandle<INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE>(r); }
inline bool operator !=(cWinHandle<INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE> l, HANDLE r) { return !(l == r); }
```

Comment: Note that when `STRICT` is defined, Win32 handle types are not simply `void*` anymore, they are typed structs instead, so you can't just use `HANDLE` generically under `STRICT`. I would suggest adding an additional template parameter to take the actual handle type: `template<T taHandleType, taHandleType taInvalidHandleValue> class cWinHandle { ... };`