# What is unique_ptr::deleter_type::pointer for?

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

`std::unique_ptr<T,D>` is specified to store not a `T*` as you might expect, but an object of type `std::unique_ptr<T,D>::pointer`. This is defined to be basically `D::pointer` if such a type exists, and `T*` otherwise. Thus, you can customize the underlying raw pointer type by customizing your deleter appropriately.

When is it a good idea to do this? What is it used for? The only discussion I've been able to find is [this note](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#673), which alludes to "better support[ing] containers and smart pointers in shared memory contexts", but that doesn't exactly shed a lot of light.

Answer (score 7):

The original motivation was to enable the use of [`boost::offset_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/interprocess/offset_ptr.html) as the representation under `unique_ptr`, which would enable the use of `unique_ptr` in process-shared memory.  Structures in process shared-memory should not contain pointers or references, only offsets.

I'm pleased to learn that the same feature can be useful in the Windows API.

Answer (score 6):

It is used when the `deleter` does not operate on `T*` values, obviously. That is why the `deleter` can specify a different data type than `T*`.  A common use case is Win32 handles:

[Using std::unique_ptr for Windows HANDLEs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184779/using-stdunique-ptr-for-windows-handles)

Comment: Nice. I think the upshot is this: A `unique_ptr<T, D>` behaves like a `T`, but its internal state is a `pointer`. In most cases, the pointer is `T *`, but it can be whatever you want, as long as its dereferencable to produce a `T` and nullable.

Comment: That said, with a small leap of faith you could use `std::unique_ptr<void, BOOL WINAPI(*)(void *)> p(..., FindVolumeClose)`, if you're willing to believe that `HANDLE = void *`. That'd require significantly less writing.

Comment: @KerrekSB: You should use `decltype()`, as an example in the other discussion showed: `std::unique_ptr<void, decltype(&FindVolumeClose)> p(..., FindVolumeClose)`

Comment: For some reason I'm not a huge fan of `decltype` in this context. I'd much rather wrap the whole thing into a maker function: `std::unique_ptr<void, BOOL WINAPI(*)(void*)> make_unique_volume(...)`. With a type alias `unique_volume_handle` that would be quite readable, and the user would never need to know the deletion function. Just my personal opinion. (OK, that's actually getting very similar to the custom deleter again, but a function call is good for exception safety reasons.)

Comment: @KerrekSB: Why do you want to be explicit about the function signature? Let the compiler work out the signature for itself, thus avoiding any possibility of user error in typing the signature, especially if the signature error changes.

Comment: Hang on, are you sure the `HANDLE` construction works? The standard says that `operator*` returns `*get()`, but also that its return type is `T &`, and that the return type of `get()` is `pointer`. That doesn't seem to add up.

Comment: (Another reason to prefer a deleter functor is that its call can be inlined, whereas a function pointer always requires indirection.)

Comment: You should never dereference a `HANDLE` (or any other Win32 handle type), so it does not make sense to use the `*` operator (or the `->` operator) when the `unique_ptr` is holding a `HANDLE` value. If you do, `*` will be a `void` (or a struct type if `STRICT` is defined), but `pointer` will be the original `HANDLE` type so `get()` will return a `HANDLE` when passed to API functions, as expected.

Comment: I understand that `get()` works, but it feels that having `T = HANDLE` violates the specified types. At least with `T = void` it would be obvious that you can't use `operator*`, and it would still be consistent.