# Calling ::GetModuleHandleEx with unique_ptr having custom deleter to handle freeing resources automatically

Tags: c++, windows, unique-ptr, custom-deleter

Do I need to free the `HMODULE` in the below code?

```
DWORD flags =
  GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS;
HMODULE hm = 0;
  ::GetModuleHandleExW(flags, L"Test.dll", &hm);
HRSRC hResource =
  ::FindResourceW(hm, MAKEINTRESOURCEW(TEST1), L"ICON");

if (hResource) {
  HGLOBAL hLoaded = LoadResource(hm, hResource);
  if (hLoaded) {
    size = (int)SizeofResource(hm, hResource);
    auto lpAddress = LockResource(hLoaded);
    //Read resource here
    UnlockResource(hLoaded);
  } else {
    //Error logging
  }
  FreeResource(hLoaded);
} else {
  //Error logging
}
```

Here I am freeing most of the resource at right place except probably `HMODULE`! Do I need to free `hm`? My understanding is that we are only getting the `HMODULE` and not loading library here, so we may not need to free it?

If the answer is yes, then I wanted to try to something like what we have here:

[Using std::unique_ptr for Windows HANDLEs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184779/)

```
struct Deleter {
    void operator()(HMODULE hModule) const
    {
        if (hModule != nullptr)
        {
            FreeLibrary(hModule);
        }
    }
};

using unique_module = std::unique_ptr<std::remove_pointer<HMODULE>::type, Deleter>;
```

But I got bit confused like how to use this `unique_module`.

Meanwhile I was writing this:

```
HMODULE hm = 0;
unique_module um {hm};

::GetModuleHandleExW(flags, L"Test.dll", &um.get());
```

Though I have not compiled and tested, this seems wrong to me, and I need input on how to correctly write this custom deleter and use it with `HMODULE` and how to call it with `::GetModuleHandleEx()`.

Comment: "[Retrieves a module handle for the specified module **and increments the module's reference count** unless GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_UNCHANGED_REFCOUNT is specified](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulehandleexw)."

Comment: This works ! But how to write custome deleter and have it work with GetModuleHandleEx ? Sample code for deleter that I shared, is that correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your use of `GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS` is wrong, as you are not passing `GetModuleHandleExW()` a memory address that is inside the module you are looking for.  If you want to find a module by its name, then DON'T use `GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS`.  In which case, you may as well just use `GetModuleHandleW()` instead, and not worry about `FreeLibrary()` at all.

Now, that being said...

To answer your actual question, the `GetModuleHandleExW()` documentation says:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulehandleexw

> Retrieves a module handle for the specified module **and increments the module's reference count unless `GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_UNCHANGED_REFCOUNT` is specified**. The module must have been loaded by the calling process.
>
> ...
>
> `[in] dwFlags`
>
> This parameter can be zero or one or more of the following values. **If the module's reference count is incremented, the caller must use the `FreeLibrary` function to decrement the reference count when the module handle is no longer needed**.

So yes, you need to call `FreeLibrary()` if you are not using `GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_UNCHANGED_REFCOUNT`, eg:

```
HMODULE hm = NULL;
::GetModuleHandleExW(0, L"Test.dll", &hm);
...
FreeLibrary(hm);
```

If you want to use `unique_ptr` with a custom `Deleter` to call `FreeLibrary()`, that is certainly doable, however you cannot obtain the address of the pointer that the `unique_ptr` holds, so you must retrieve the `HMODULE` *before* you then construct the `unique_ptr` from it, eg:

```
HMODULE hm = NULL;
::GetModuleHandleExW(0, L"Test.dll", &hm);
unique_module um {hm};
```

Otherwise, you could simply forget about the `Deleter` and just use `GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_UNCHANGED_REFCOUNT` instead if you must use `GetModuleHandleExW()`, or just use `GetModuleHandleW()` instead.