# c++ passing nullptr through multiple functions

Tags: c++, nullptr

I'm having trouble with some code, where I need to pass a pointer through multiple layers of functions. The pointer can be null so I've an overload for the final function for the case of nullptr. Conceptual I've something like this:

```
void test_ptr(std::nullptr_t)
{
  std::cout << "nullptr" << std::endl;
}
void test_ptr(double *d)
{
  std::cout << *d << std::endl;
}

void test(double *d)
{
  test_ptr(d);
}

int main()
{
  test(nullptr);
}
```

For me, the ideal behaviour would be, if `test` calls the first version of `test_ptr`, but this isn't the case. Is there any chance to manipulate `test` so that it calls the "right" version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you check for `nullptr` in the beginning of the `double*` function?

In your case, you do not need to overload the function for `nullptr_t`. The use of `std::nullptr_t` is explained in this question:
[What are the uses of the type `std::nullptr_t`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066721/what-are-the-uses-of-the-type-stdnullptr-t)

So this means for you: If you had another `test_ptr` function, that accepts a pointer type, then you would need the overloaded one with `std::nullptr_t`. But with just one `test_ptr` function, it is not necessary.

Comment: Of course your right that the overload is not necessary but I personally prefer to have to separate cases which should be indicated by two different overloads. Though if I don't get it to work that way, I will implement it as you suggested.

Answer (score 5):

You'll need a function template:

```
void test_ptr(std::nullptr_t)
{
  std::cout << "nullptr" << std::endl;
}
void test_ptr(double *d)
{
  std::cout << *d << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
void test(T d)
{
  test_ptr(d);
}

int main()
{
  test(nullptr);
}
```

In your code, the argument is `double*`, regardless from what type it was converted from.
A `static_assert` ensuring that `T` is a pointer type might also be in order:

```
static_assert(std::is_pointer<T>{} || std::is_same<T, std::nullptr_t>{},
    "Not a pointer type!");
```

NOTE: C++14 also introduced [`std::is_null_pointer`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_null_pointer).

Answer (score 1):

After the call to `test(nullptr)` you have a `double*` with a *value* that happens to be null, but the value is a run-time property, its static type is `double*` and so `test_ptr(d)` will always choose `test_ptr(double*)`. Overloading chooses a function at compile-time based on types, not based on run-time values.