# Check if two std::function are Equal

Tags: c++, function, operators, equals, std

If I have two `std::function`s, how can I check whether both hold the same function or not?

Additional Information: I have a vector of functions `std::vector<std::function<void()>>` and before adding another function to the vector I want to check if it already is contained.

Comment: Lambdas can be exactly equivalent, but since they don't have an == operator, you can't compare them. You're Better off using a unique_ptr

Comment: Using an unique_ptr how could that handle functions?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629835/why-is-stdfunction-not-equality-comparable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont think that they both can be compared. Here is an [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/function/faq.html) to explain some points on std::function comparison

Answer (score 0):

Generally `std::function` and `boost::function` are not comparable because they need their stored object be comparable but not all function objects and also lambdas have `operator==` so `std` or `boost` functions have no way to compare them