# Multimap with std::function as value

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a `std::multimap` where values are of type `std::function`. Since there is no comparison for `std::function` - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629835/why-is-stdfunction-not-equality-comparable) - it seems to be no way to remove a specific element from this multimap. I guess the same is true if you'd like to, for example, remove an element by value from e.g. a `std::list` or `std::vector`.

My use case is a function which takes a callback an argument (`std::function`). The callback should be called when a specific event occurs. However, there could be other circumstances where the callee want to 'deregister' the callback before it have fired.

Initially I though, let me just wrap the `std::function` in a struct and insert pointers to this struct in my map. However, this didn't prove feasible as the interface user shouldn't have to wrap callbacks in a struct and store pointer values.

The best idea I have at the moment is returning an id when the callback is registered - which must be stored if the callee want's t to have the option to cancel the callback later on.

Any ideas on my pickle?

Comment: Your "id" suggestion is what I would do.

Comment: `std::multimap` doesn't invalidate iterators on insertion / erasing so you could just store the iterator of a newly inserted element, and use it for erasing the element. Even though I don't know `std::multimap`very well, I use this method regularly for `std::list` and this works like a charm. Since the constraints on iterators seem to be the same I see no reason why it shouldn't work unless I missed some detail.

Comment: I've ended up combining these two comments. I return an id, and the id I return is the iterator which "holds" the entry in the multimap. This makes removing very easy `mulitmap.erase(it)`. I also typedef'd the iterator so that it is something like `class::id_t`. Thank you for the input

Comment: I extracted the code which spawned the original question to a library, it can be found here: https://github.com/noseglid/libde

Answer (score 0):

If the caller is supposed to keep some kind of token (`id` in your case), why not just wrap the `std::function` in a `std::shared_ptr` and let the caller provide/keep that instead of some made-up ID? The `std::multimap` would then store the `std::shared_ptr<std::function<...>>` as its value directly instead of the `std::function`.

That way, you can easily remove it later and you will not copy the `std::function` itself around, which might also be a [potentially costly operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057382/what-is-the-performance-overhead-of-stdfunction). When the caller uses `std::make_shared<std::function<...>>(...)` it could be a real alternative IMHO.

Comment: If you store a shared_ptr, how is the client supposed to remove it?

Comment: I don't think this is correct. If one place sharing a pointer makes it nullptr, the other place will still have it's previous view of the ptr - that's the point of shared, surely?

Comment: @doctorlove I think you are missing the point. What I proposed is supposed to solve the initial problem the OP asked about (and it does that). It does open up a certain potential of misuse, but that is beyond the scope of this. My answer was meant to give a start to the OP to overcome `std::function`'s lack of a comparison operator.