# Comparison operator with std::function

Tags: c++, c++11

How can I compare two `std::function`?

`==` only seems to compare to a null pointer: 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator_cmp

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629835/why-is-stdfunction-not-equality-comparable

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible. `std::function` can store any copyable and callable object. This includes objects that are not comparable. Since `std::function` can contain objects that are not comparable, it cannot provide any comparison operations that will work for all contained objects.

If you want this functionality, you'll have to implement your own type-erased `function` template that requires the contained objects to be comparable.