# Find duplicate in templated vector

Tags: c++, templates

I have a templated `class Timer`

```
template<typename Clock, typename Duration>
class Timer
{
public:
    void Register(const std::function<void(const std::chrono::time_point<Clock> &timePoint)> &eventHandler);

private:
    std::vector<std::function<void(const std::chrono::time_point<Clock> &timePoint)>> eventHandlers;

// Some more stuff.
};
```

Now I would like to find duplicate entries in `Register` and that's the problem.
I tried different approaches using `std::find` and a simple `for` loop.

The best I could get so far (removed namespaces for readability):

```
typename vector<function<void(const time_point<Clock> &timePoint)>>::iterator it;
for(it = eventHandlers.begin(); it != eventHandlers.end(); ++it)
{
}
```

My problem is to compare the parameter of `Register` with `it`.
I tried several things like:

```
typename function<void(const time_point<Clock> &timePoint)> &f = &(*it);
if(f == eventHandler)
{
    // Duplicate
}
```

... and some other more complicated approaches but none of them worked.
I have some trouble solving this as I usually code in C# and therefor I'm not used to do templating in C++.
How can I solve this and are there even more elegant solutions to this problem?

Edit:
I usually get this error:

```
binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::function<void (const std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock,std::chrono::system_clock::duration> &)>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Comment: The issue here isn't with templating, but with the fact that `std::function`s are [not equality comparable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629835/why-is-stdfunction-not-equality-comparable). What does it mean for two things you pass into `Timer::Register` to be equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note:

```
typename function<void(const time_point<Clock> &timePoint)> &f = &(*it);
if(f == eventHandler)
{
    // Duplicate
}
```

I think you mean to put `typename function<void(const time_point<Clock> &timePoint)> *f`, as `&(*it)` returns a pointer type rather than a reference.

---

**Update**:

`std::function` is not `==` comparable, so you can do the following:

not use `std::function` but instead use a function pointer like so (using the typedef again):

```
typedef void(*name_of_type)(const time_point<Clock>&)>
```

And then replace name_of_type with whatever name you want.

This way you can use the `operator==` with the function pointers

---

**Update #2**:

I will clarify it all by putting all into your class:

```
template<typename Clock, typename Duration>
class Timer
{
public:
    typedef void(*name_of_type)(const time_point<Clock>&)>

    void Register(name_of_type eventHandler);

private:
    std::vector<name_of_type> eventHandlers;
// Some more stuff.
};
```

With the for loop, you can then do something like:

[non-c++11]

```
typename vector<name_of_type>::iterator it;
for(it = eventHandlers.begin(); it != eventHandlers.end(); ++it)
{
//do what you want with *it
}
```

[c++11 onwards]

```
for(auto& x: eventHandlers)
{
//do what you want with x
}
```

Comment: The first half of you answer does not answer the question and is superfluous.  It should either go after you "Update" or be removed.

Comment: @NathanOliver - I removed it now :)