# Using erase-remove idiom for function<void()>

Tags: c++, functional-programming, erase-remove-idiom

Stacked people.

Iam trying to implement an observer(esque?) pattern for my program. I have a component which stores what functions should be called if an event occours. My prolem is that i dont know how should i erase my function from the container, if the need arises. Tried storing the functions by reference, but iam not sure how to do that(or if thats possible.)

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

enum class EVENT_TYPE{ 
    anEvent 
};

class EventableComponent{
    map<EVENT_TYPE, vector<function<void()>>> listeners;
public:
    void trigger(EVENT_TYPE _et){
        for(auto& it : listeners[_et]){
            it();
        }
    }

    void registerListener(EVENT_TYPE _et, function<void()> _fn){
        listeners[_et].push_back(_fn);
    };

    void removeListener(EVENT_TYPE _et, function<void()> _fn){
        //error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::function<void (void)>' 
        //(or there is no acceptable conversion)        
        listeners[_et].erase(remove(listeners[_et].begin(), listeners[_et].end(), _fn), listeners[_et].end());
    };
};

int main(){
    EventableComponent ec;

    // this would become a member function for a class  somewhere down the line
    auto fn = [](){cout << "Hello.\n"; };

    ec.registerListener(EVENT_TYPE::anEvent, fn);
    ec.trigger(EVENT_TYPE::anEvent);

    ec.removeListener(EVENT_TYPE::anEvent, fn);
    ec.trigger(EVENT_TYPE::anEvent);

    cin.get();
    return 0;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem can be reduced to the fact that two `std::function` instances cannot be compared for equality. `std::remove` requires `operator==`, and `std::function` does not have it. See ["Why is std::function not equality comparable?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629835/why-is-stdfunction-not-equality-comparable).

Consider the following situation.

Let's say you defined two lambdas in your `main`:

```
auto fn = [](){cout << "Hello.\n"; };
auto fn2 = [](){cout << "Hello.\n"; };
```

Now, are those two equal or not? They do the same thing, but perhaps this is sheer coincidence. Would they become unequal if the second `"Hello"` became `"Hello2"`? Would they become unequal if the second one was no longer a lambda but a real function `void f()`?

The thing is that there can be no *generally* useful definition of equality for function objects, so it's up to you to define what equality really means in the context of *your* program.

You have several options to solve the problem at hand. One would be to operate on *pointers* to `std::function` objects. Pointers can be compared, and proper use of `std::unique_ptr` makes sure that deallocation is handled correctly.

Or you assign an identifier to every `std::function` you use. See the following modified example of your code in which direct storage of `std::function<void()>` in the vector is replaced with a custom type `EventFunction` that maps an `int` to the function object. The example uses `std::remove_if` to compare only the `int`s:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

enum class EVENT_TYPE{ 
    anEvent 
};

struct EventFunction {
    function<void()> f;
    int id;
};

class EventableComponent{
    map<EVENT_TYPE, vector<EventFunction>> listeners;
public:
    void trigger(EVENT_TYPE _et){
        for(auto& it : listeners[_et]){
            it.f();
        }
    }

    void registerListener(EVENT_TYPE _et, EventFunction _fn){
        listeners[_et].push_back(_fn);
    };

    void removeListener(EVENT_TYPE _et, int function_id){
        //error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::function<void (void)>' 
        //(or there is no acceptable conversion)     
        listeners[_et].erase(remove_if(listeners[_et].begin(), listeners[_et].end(),
               [&](EventFunction const& e) { return e.id == function_id; }), listeners[_et].end());
    };
};

int main(){
    EventableComponent ec;

    // this would become a member function for a class  somewhere down the line
    auto fn = [](){cout << "Hello.\n"; };

    ec.registerListener(EVENT_TYPE::anEvent, EventFunction{ fn, 1 });
    ec.trigger(EVENT_TYPE::anEvent);

    ec.removeListener(EVENT_TYPE::anEvent, 1);
    ec.trigger(EVENT_TYPE::anEvent);
};
```

---

> Tried storing the functions by reference, but iam not sure how to do
>   that(or if thats possible.)

It's not possible because you cannot store references in standard-library containers. But I suppose the idea is similar to the one with pointers I mentioned above.